# Server to client message not getting delivered

Tags: c, sockets, udp, client

Client code

```
  #include  <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <netinet/in.h>
#include    <arpa/inet.h>
#include    <sys/socket.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <time.h>
#define     MAX 1024
int main ( int argc, char ** argv)
{

    printf("Check point 1\n");
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Error!! Provide a correct port\n");
        exit (0);
    }


    unsigned char buff[MAX];
    int port = atoi(argv[1]);
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in myAddr, Addr;
    unsigned char temp[MAX];
    char buffer [MAX];

    socklen_t addr_size;
    addr_size = sizeof(Addr);


    //_os_getime();
    printf("Check point 2\n");
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0))< 0)
    {
        printf ( "%d", sockfd);
            perror("socket failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&myAddr,'\0', sizeof(myAddr));
    myAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    myAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    myAddr.sin_addr.s_addr =inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    printf ("Check point 3");
    strcpy(buff, "ABCDE\n");
    if((sendto(sockfd, buff, MAX, 0 , (struct sockaddr*) &myAddr, sizeof(myAddr)))<0)
    {
        perror("Sending failed--");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

    printf ("Check point 4");

    if((recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0 , (struct sockaddr*) &Addr, &addr_size))<0)
    {
        perror("Receiving failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf ( "%s", buff);


    close(sockfd);
    return 0;

}
```

Server Code

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
/*
#include    <modes.h>
#include    <events.h>
#include    <process.h>
#include    <alarm.h>
#include    <signal.h>
#include    <module.h>
#include    <sg_codes.h>
#include    <sgstat.h>
#include    <sys/types.h>
*/
#include    <netinet/in.h>
#include    <arpa/inet.h>
#include    <sys/socket.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <time.h>
#define     MAX 1024


int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Error!! Provide a correct port\n");
        exit (0);
    }   


    int port = atoi(argv[1]);
    char buff[MAX];
    char buffer [MAX];
    int sockfd, clientfd;
    struct sockaddr_in myAddr, Addr;


    socklen_t addr_size;

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0))< 0)
    {
        printf ( "%d", sockfd);
            perror("socket failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&myAddr,'\0', sizeof(myAddr));
    myAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    myAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    myAddr.sin_addr.s_addr =inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    if ((bind (sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &myAddr, sizeof(myAddr)))<0)
    {
        perror("Binding failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    addr_size = sizeof(Addr);


    int recv = recvfrom(sockfd, buff, MAX, 0 , (struct sockaddr*) &Addr, &addr_size);
    printf ( "%s", buff);   

    strcpy(buffer, "EFGH");
    if((sendto(sockfd, buffer, MAX, 0 , (struct sockaddr*) &myAddr, sizeof(myAddr)))<0)
    {
        perror("Sending failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }   
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

This is a simple code on socket programming
When I am starting the server and then the client, the message ABCDE is sent to server and message is getting printed at the server and the server is getting terminated.
But at the client side the code is not getting terminated and getting executed only till checkpoint 2. I am not understanding why checkpoint 3 is not getting printed even though the next line is working.
And ofcourse, the message from server to client is also not getting printed

Comment: You should add a `\n` to the checkpoint 3 to force `stdout` flushing

Comment: Your client and server seems to be on the same computer (`127.0.0.1`) and to read/write on the same port. You should try to use two ports, one the client -> server communication, one other for the server -> client.

Comment: You send a lot of uninitialized memory: `strcpy(buff, "ABCDE\n");
    if((sendto(sockfd, buff, MAX, 0 , (struct sockaddr*) &myAddr, sizeof(myAddr)))<0)` Only 6 bytes of `MAX` hold some useful content.

Comment: @Gerhardh, I know, how does that matter here. its just a small example program. will be building bigger program on it.
IT doesnt solve any problem even if I initialize or decrease the memory

Comment: @purplepsycho, so u mean to say, i should use two diffetent port numbers as command line arguments eg for server 1234 and for client 4321
or something else.

Comment: @ purplepsycho putting '\n' worked, but still message from server to client still not working